# How can I prove that eventually one function will overtake another, and find when?

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

Given for example 2 functions,$\ n^{100} $ and$\ 2^n$. I know that$\ 2^n$ grows faster and that therefore there is some$\ n$ where it will eventually overtake $\ n^{100} $ but how can I prove this, and also maybe find that$\ n$?

Comment: If there is a point from which on the function that was smaller than the other before becomes the function being bigger than the other, you find this point by calculating the intersection of these points. Moreover, to calculate which function is larger in the limit, consider the ratio of your functions. If this tends to a value greater than one. the denominator is larger in the limit. Similar for smaller than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elementary way of proving that exponentials grow faster is to use the binomial expansion.

To illustrate, here $(1+1)^r=1+r+\binom r2+\binom r3+\dots$, where we can choose $r$ large enough for all the terms we need to exist on the right-hand side.

To show that $2^r$ is eventually larger than $r^2$ we take the term $\binom r3=\frac {r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!}$ from the expansion and observe that this is a cubic in $r$ with positive leading term, and is therefore eventually greater than any quadratic in $r$ with positive leading term, and hence eventually greater that $r^2$. Since this is just one of the positive terms on the right-hand side, we have for large enough $r$ $$2^r=(1+1)^r\gt\binom r3\gt r^2$$ with some very crude estimates. For $r^{100}$ we can use the same argument with $\binom r{101}$, which is a polynomial of degree $101$ in $r$ and positive leading term, to give, for large enough $r$ $$2^r=(1+1)^r\gt\binom r{101}\gt r^{100}$$

The estimates here are very crude indeed, and are not good enough to give transition values for $r$. But they are good enough to furnish a proof of the kind you wanted for the comparison of growth rates.

Answer (score 3):

Solve $2^n > n^{100} \iff n\ln 2>100\ln n\iff \dfrac{n}{\ln n} > \dfrac{100}{\ln 2}$. Let $n = 2^k$, then $ \dfrac{n}{\ln n} = \dfrac{2^k}{k}$,and you solve $2^k > 100k$. Observe the first integer solution $k$ for this is $k = 10$. Thus $n = 2^{10} = 1,024$ .

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $2^n$ grows faster than $n^{100}$ then you understand that it is a special case of the more general result that exponential functions grow faster than polynomials.

Moreover knowing this fact may mean one has heard or read this somewhere, but in a deeper and crucial sense knowing it means one knows the proof of the following theorem:

> **Theorem**: If $a>1$ then $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^b} {a^n} =0$ for any real number $b$.

The proof is not difficult. Let's choose a positive integer $k$ such that $k>b$ and set $a=1+c$ so that $c>0$. Next using binomial theorem we have $$a^n=(1+c) ^n>\binom {n} {k+1} c^{k+1}$$ if $n>k+1$. Thus we have $$0<\frac{n^b}{a^n}<\dfrac{n^k}{{\displaystyle \binom{n} {k+1}c^{k+1} }}$$ for $n>k+1$. Using Squeeze Theorem it follows that $n^b/a^n\to 0$.

This proves that if $a>1$ then eventually $a^n$ will become far greater than $n^b$ no matter what $b$ is. Finding the first value of $n$ where $a^n>n^b$ requires some numerical analysis based on values of $a, b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda > 0$ and consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {x^n\over e^{\lambda x}}.$$
This limit can be reduced using L'hospital's rule to 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} {nx^{n-1}\over \lambda e^{\lambda x}}.$$
Repeating, the power whittles away whilst the exponential remains on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^{100}=2^n$$
$$100\ln(n)=n\ln(2)$$
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=\frac{\ln(2)}{100}$$
let $n=e^{-x}$
$$xe^{x}=\frac{-\ln(2)}{100}$$
then you can use the Lambert W function $W(x)$ to find the value of $x$, then work backwards to $n$

EDIT:
$$x=W\left(\frac{-\ln(2)}{100}\right)$$
$$n=-\ln\left[W\left(\frac{-\ln(2)}{100}\right)\right]$$